# `py_function` causes `ragged_batch()` not working in `tf.data`

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord, tf.data.dataset

I'm working on an object detection project, and use `tf.data.Dataset` input pipeline to load local data. Because object detection requires not only image but also annotations, and the different dimension of annotations makes it even harder. I tried several ways but none of them works. Here's my attempts, and I'm exhausted of ideas. Very appreciate for your help!

### Parse XML

My local data is in Pascal VOC format. First, I used `.from_tensor_slices()` to get `annotation_files` paths, and parse them to get image path, and finally `.ragged_batch()` them. But during `.map(load)`, it automatically converted string into `Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)`, which cannot be used in many libraries like XML parser `ElementTree`. Then I used `tf.py_function()` to convert it back into Python string.
And them find it a TensorFlow bug: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/60710

```py
annotation_files = [
    '082f7a7f-IMG_0512.xml',
    '4f4c7f54-IMG_0511.xml',
    '5381454b-IMG_0510.xml',
    '05517884-IMG_0514.xml'
]

def load(annotationFile):
    # load annotation (boxes, class ids)
    def _loadAnnotation(annotationFile):
        thisBoxes = []
        thisClassIDs = []
        annotationFile = annotationFile.numpy().decode("utf-8")
        root = ET.parse(annotationFile).getroot()
        for object in root.findall("object"):
            # load bounding boxes
            bndbox = object.find("bndbox")
            xmin = int(bndbox.find("xmin").text)
            ymin = int(bndbox.find("ymin").text)
            xmax = int(bndbox.find("xmax").text)
            ymax = int(bndbox.find("ymax").text)
            thisBoxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
            # load class IDs
            className = object.find("name").text
            classID = classNames.index(className)
            thisClassIDs.append(classID)
        # image file path
        imageFile = imageFolder + "/" + root.find('filename').text
        return (imageFile, tf.cast(thisBoxes, dtype=tf.float32), tf.cast(thisClassIDs, dtype=tf.float32))
    
    imageFile, thisBoxes, thisClassIDs = tf.py_function(_loadAnnotation, [annotationFile], [tf.string, tf.float32, tf.float32])
    
    # load image
    image = tf.io.read_file(imageFile)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)

    # package annotation (boxes, class ids) to dictionary
    bounding_boxes = {
        "boxes": tf.cast(thisBoxes, dtype=tf.float32),
        "classes": tf.cast(thisClassIDs, dtype=tf.float32)
    }

    return {"images": tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32), "bounding_boxes": bounding_boxes}

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(annotation_files)
dataset = dataset.map(load)
dataset = dataset.ragged_batch(4)
```

### `pickle`

Then, I tried to package one record of data into a single file with `pickle` to prevent parsing with `ET`. Unfortunately, `pickle` also needs Python string. Same problem as first attempt, it not works.

### TFReocrd

After that, I tried to store data into TFRecord and load them with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset()`. But problem comes when writing TFRecord. It comes an error `TypeError: Value must be iterable`. During search I find [this discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9554). It seems I must reshape my tensor to flatten it, and then bring it back to N-dimension when using. But because the unknown dimension of bounding boxes, which is why I want to use `ragged_batch`, it's impossible for me to flatten them.

```py
def serializeTFRecord(data):
    image = data["images"]
    classes = data["bounding_boxes"]["classes"]
    boxes = data["bounding_boxes"]["boxes"]

    feature = {
        "images": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=image)),
        "bounding_boxes": {
            "classes": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=classes)),
            "boxes": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=boxes))
        }
    }

    exampleProto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    return exampleProto.SerializeToString()
```

Comment: **Pointer**: a. convert XML to CSV format. b1. now you can use CSV in the tf.data API. b2. transform CSV to TFRecord. IMO, CSV format, in this case, is convenient and useful. You can do easily EDA and easily transform it into a different format, i.e. tfrecord, JSON (coco-style), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an arduous attempting and trying, I eventually come with an idea of how to fix this `py_function` bug. According to [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35108), the return value of `py_function` lost the information of its shape and rank. So the easiest solution can bring it back to life is to manually set those information by `tensor.set_shape([None, None])`, the number of `None` should be the dimension (the number of axis) of that tensor. Below are a small demo showing that it works.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def processing(data):
    def _processing(data):
        arr = [range(data), range(data)]
        arr = tf.cast(arr, tf.float32)
        print(f"Inside py_function arr shape: {arr.shape}")
        return arr
    
    arr = tf.py_function(_processing, [data], tf.float32)
    print(f"Outside py_function arr shape: {arr.shape}")
    arr.set_shape([None, None])
    return arr

list = [1,2,3,1]

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list)
ds = ds.map(processing)
ds = ds.ragged_batch(4)

for data in ds:
    print("==========")
    print(data)
```